# How do you pass Menuconfig variables to your cmake file ( in ESP-IDF )

Tags: makefile, cmake, esp32

I am trying to configure to my build process for ESP-IDF to slim down the build. What I have tried : I've added custom entries to the menuconfig:

```
    menu "Install Sensor Device Drivers"
        config LISD3H_CHECK
            bool "Include LISD3H Accel Sensor"
            default "n"      
            help
                Install required drivers for LISD3H and check if device present 
        config SHT30_CHECK
            bool "Include SHT30 Temp & Hum Sensor"
            default "n"      
            help
                Install required drivers for SHT30 and check if device present
    endmenu
```

and tried using these to reduce unnecessary components getting compiled into the project. The config variables are correctly created and accessible within the source code. Now, I tried to control the build within the top level cmake file:

```
set(component_dirs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../components/comp1")
message(STATUS ${component_dirs})

message(STATUS ${CONFIG_LISD3H_CHECK})
message(STATUS ${CONFIG_SHT30_CHECK})

if(CONFIG_LISD3H_CHECK)  
    list(APPEND component_dirs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../components/comp2" )
    message(STATUS ${component_dirs})
else()
    message(STATUS "config not equal to whategver...")
endif()
```

However, the if statement is always false because cmake cannot see the CONFIG_XXXX variables from Kconfig (the messages are blank) Is there a way to access Kconfig varaibles inside cmake? Or a means of using menuconfig to control the build?

Basically, How do you exclude a component from the build? Should I just use C precompile directives inside the source code and ignore what gets compiled, since it will get optimised out of the final binary?

Answer (score 1):

You should be on the correct path according to the ESP IDF [build system documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#adding-conditional-configuration). Did you add your options to `Kconfig` in the main component? Note that you need to actually *run* `idf.py menuconfig` and choose your configuration before it becomes visible to cmake, after which the root `sdkconfig` file should have them set.

For example, in the ESP IDF project's `main/Kconfig.projbuild` file I added

```
menu "Test Configuration"

    config TESTOPTION_YAY
        bool "Enable test option"

endmenu
```

Then in the project root `CMakeLists.txt` I added:

```
message(STATUS CONFIG_TESTOPTION_YAY: ${CONFIG_TESTOPTION_YAY})
```

Now I run `idf.py menuconfig` and set the test option on or off. Subsequently I build with `idf.py build` - the build log shows `-- CONFIG_TESTOPTION_YAY:y` or `-- CONFIG_TESTOPTION_YAY:` depending on the choice I made.

Comment: I added the stuff into the Kconfig for the component and then ran idf.py. The values do appear there and are subsequently accessible from the code. What I was trying to do (perhaps naively) was figure out is if I can access those values from Cmake. I'd like to have one single source of truth for the build. I.e. I set values in menuconfig, and the build is modified to exclude unneeded components etc.

Comment: But you *can* access those values from CMake. I have done this (according to instructions) and it works fine. If it doesn't work for you, dig deeper.

Comment: Updated the answer with a trivial example, perhaps it helps.